# Win 10 проблемы с локальной сетью

Tags: сеть, 1с, ping, локальная-сеть

проблема в доступе по локальной сети 1с 8.3 заходит по 10-15 минут, а иногда вообще виснет после выбора файловой базы и не заходит, 1с 7.7 документы проводит по 1 минуте и заходит в базу 3-4мин и так когда ходишь по папкам которые в общем доступе чувствуются задержки . Есть главный ПК(Глав.бух. pentium gold g7400/8gb(ddr4)/ssd-sata) и 4 ПК обычных бухгалтеров 2 на win7 и 2 на win10. Вот основные затыки на win 10 там ПК то же новые на i3 10100. На win7 относительно старые. Когда пингуешь с компьютера на win10 главный ПК 10-15% пакетов теряются с надписью "превышен интервал ожидания" хотя на ПК с win7 такого нет. Я менял провода не помогло, игрался с настройками локальных политик, антивируса, брандмаузера и общего доступа тоже не помогло. На win 10 везде включил smb 1.0. Сеть построена на роутере Tp-link tl-wr840n и коммутатора mercusys ms105. Один кабель с главного ПК в роутер и один кабель с роутера до коммутатора. В сети обычно 11 машин в роботе.
Подскажите пожалуйста куда смотреть что делать.

Comment: Недавно столкнулся почти с такой же проблемой. IP-адреса откуда на компах, DHCP от коммутатора?

Comment: Перегружать Tp-link tl-wr840n пробовали? Вообще, иметь Tp-link tl-wr840n и требовать от него адекватной работы на такой парк - это немного запредельно. "игрался с настройками локальных политик, антивируса, брандмаузера" никак не влияет на "15% пакетов теряются". Смените на время роутер, посмотрите. Если дело в нем, то банально перепрошейте свой TPLINK родной прошивкой, а еще лучше DD-WRT/OpenWRT (если поддерживается).

Comment: @ratabor dhcp с роутера и у всех машин ip адрес в локальной сети выставлен руками принудительно.

Comment: Так DHCP или "выставлен руками принудительно"?

Comment: @void - у 11 компьютеров ip выставлен в ручную а для мобильных телефонов  подключенных по вайфай выставляется с помощью dhcp.

Comment: Ну проверьте, нет ли петлей, нет ли одинаковых IP. Если на TL-WR840N стоит что-то типа DD-WRT, то у них известная проблема с NetBios. Да и могут быть выставлены разные параметры, которые могут влиять (всех не перечислить). Вы как-то все же детали напишите, а pentium gold g7400/8gb(ddr4)/ssd-sata мало кому чем поможет. Как я писал, попробуйте прошить роутер родной же прошивкой - делается из браузера двумя кликами.

Comment: Как вариант, - уберите в настройках сети на проблемной/всех компах IPv6; Выполните на проблемных/всех компах netsh winsock reset Проверьте роуты, настройки DNS, попробуйте подключаться к бд 1С указывая IP адрес; И наконец - убедитесь что на компах НЕ установлен сетевой принтер (который на момент подключения недоступен)